# MinHashing and Hash Digests/Signatures

Tags: data-mining, similarities

Nilsimsa and SimHash are two similarity hash algorithms that produce a single hash digest/signature per document. Comparing two documents is as simple as computing the hamming distance between two hash digests/signatures. Neither algorithm needs to know about other documents when computing a hash for any given document.

I've been looking for more algorithms that work this way. I came upon MinHash (AKA min-wise independent permutations) which on the surface appears to have these characteristics but everything I read says it needs a collection of documents in order to compute the hashes for any document in the collection. Is this correct? Is there anyway to get a single hash for a single document independent of the rest of the documents in the collection using MinHash?

Answer (score 0):

That's not correct. MinHash is a function whose domain a set of elements (a single document) and whose range is a vector of integers (the digest or sketch). The MinHash of a single document is independent of all other documents that you may consider.